# Remove consecutive duplicates from nested list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, python-itertools

I have a nested list that has the following structure:

```
mylist = [['A', 'Car', '15'], ['A', 'Car', '15'], ['A', 'Plane', '16'], ['A', 'Bike', '20'], ['A', 'Car', '16'], ['A', 'Boat', '16']]
```

It's super long, with around 10 million elements. And I have many of these lists. What I want to do is:

*If the third items (the string numbers) of each consecutive element from `mylist` are  duplicates, remove the elements that contain this duplicate.*

For example:

`['A', 'Car', '15']` and `['A', 'Car', '15']` are consecutive elements from `mylist`, and they both contain `'15'`, so they are consecutive duplicates, and one should be removed.

Similarly, `['A', 'Car', '16']` and `['A', 'Boat', '16']` are consecutive and both contain `'16'`, so one should be removed.

So, what I would end up with is:

```
newlist = [['A', 'Car', '15'], ['A', 'Plane', '16'], ['A', 'Bike', '20'], ['A', 'Car', '16']]
```

I initially wrote this:

```
for ele in mylist:
    eleindex = mylist.index(ele)
    previousele = mylist[eleindex-1]
    if float(ele[2]) != float(previousele[2]):
        newlist.append(ele)
```

Unfortunately, the code I wrote took way to long for such long lists. So, I began looking online and learned that the `itertools` library (using `groupby`) is useful and **very fast** at doing these kinds of things. I then found some examples that I tried emulating, however, they were mainly for simple lists - not something a little more complicated like my situation. After tinkering around, I wasn't able to figure out how to use it for my nested lists.

So, does anyone know how to do this very quickly? Also, if you have a solution that will be faster than `itertools`, that's even better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = [['A', 'Car', '15'], ['A', 'Car', '15'], ['A', 'Plane', '16'], ['A', 'Bike', '20'], ['A', 'Car', '16'], ['A', 'Boat', '16']]

out = [next(g) for _, g in groupby(mylist, lambda k: k[2])]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[['A', 'Car', '15'], ['A', 'Plane', '16'], ['A', 'Bike', '20'], ['A', 'Car', '16']]
```

Benchmark (with 10_000_000 item list):

```
from timeit import timeit
from random import randint
from itertools import groupby

mylist = []
for i in range(10_000_000):
    mylist.append(['X', 'X', str(randint(0, 20))])

def f1():
    out = [next(g) for _, g in groupby(mylist, lambda k: k[2])]
    return out

t1 = timeit(lambda: f1(), number=1)

print(t1)
```

This prints on my machine (AMD 2400G, Python 3.8):

```
2.408908904006239
```